# Is it dangerous to name a protobuf field message?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Consider the following protobuf:

```
message SendRequest {
  /** The raw text of the message that the caller wishes to send. */
  optional string message = 1;
}
```

Note that the string `message` is being used as a field name. The protobuf compilers seems to be fine with this, even though `message` is the protobuf keyword.

Is this usage kosher in the sense that keywords are defined by some standard to be ignored in field names, or could this break my application in the future?

Comment: This is a great question. I think in this case it should be fine (essentially a contextual keyword rather than a reserved keyword), but ... can I name a message `repeated`? Any other edge cases? Ultimately the specification here is rather informal, to the point where I guess you could say that "protoc", as a reference implementation, defines the DSL. I bet there's a few cases I don't handle identically, though! (I have my own independent proto parser)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible because in runtime a proto field is identified by their id (in your case 1) and not with their name.